# Having trouble recalculating area and perimeter

Tags: java

Write an application class called `RectangleApp.java`. In this class:

1. read in values for the length and width from the user
2. create a new Rectangle object using these values
3. calculate and print out the area and perimeter of this rectangle
4. read in two more values from the user,
5. change the length and width of the rectangle to these values using
   the setter methods from the Rectangle class
6. re-calculate the area and perimeter. Print out the new area and
   perimeter.

I have gone as far as part 5. of the question. I'm not sure what it wants me to change in the setter methods. Here is my setter:

```
public void setLength(double newLength) {
     length = newLength;
}

public void setWidth(double newWidth) {
     width = newWidth;
}
```

Here is a link to the full file: http://www.filedropper.com/rectangle1
http://www.filedropper.com/rectangleapp

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: (e) is just asking you to call the setters with the new length and width you just read in from the user in part (d). (f) is asking you to do (c) again, now that the length and width have changed.

Comment: The problem is I dont know what to do in part 5

Comment: So do I just replicate what I already have on the setter methods just with new ones?

Comment: You have done step 5 now do step 6. Sometimes these assignments are as simple as they look.

Comment: Step 5 doesn't ask you to replicate anything. It asks you to call the setters with the new values.

Comment: @Tom No, just call them, passing in the values you read in in step (d).

Comment: Can any of use have a look at my code and tell me what I need to add in it.

Comment: So how do I call it again?